# findstr on multipule values

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop

Please forgive me if this is glaring obvious but I have the behaviour of this for loop, which loops through certain named directories (US_Site4 etc.) and reads a config file in each of them to run a command separately for each:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


REM The Root to start searching from
SET "InstallSets=D:\InstallSets"

REM Folders to not search with in
SET "ExcludeStr=findstr /I /v ^"\Master Files \Training \Software^""

REM 
SET "InstallSets=D:\InstallSets"

for /f "delims=*" %%F IN ('dir /s /b /on "!InstallSets!" ^| findstr /E /C:"Config.xml" ^| !ExcludeStr!') do (
    (ECHO "%%F"| findstr /I "\US_Site4 \US_Site5" 1>NUL) && (
       ECHO "%%F"...
   )
)
```

And I would like to be able replicated in a more user configurable way for furure additions, i.e. settings a variable at the top of a batch file, e.g.:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM The Root to start searching from
SET "InstallSets=D:\InstallSets"

REM Folders to not search with in
SET "ExcludeStr=findstr /I /v ^"\Master Files \Training \Software^""

REM Folders to search in only
SET "DoOnlyStr=findstr /I ^"\US_Site4 \US_Site5^" 1>NUL"

for /f "delims=*" %%F IN ('dir /s /b /on "!InstallSets!" ^| findstr /E /C:"Config.xml" ^| !ExcludeStr!') do (
    (ECHO "%%F"|  %DoOnlyStr%) && (
       ECHO "%%F"...
   )
)
```

The first one brings back 2 results which are site4 and 5 as expected, however the second one brings back 4 (The 2 I wanted but duplicated). Why is this and how could get a "user friendly" configurable version like just setting the variable? I want to then later make a second file with `findstr /I /V` to do the opposite and do everything else BUT Site4 and 5.

Kind regards

Adam

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the escaped quotes in your variables like `ExcludeStr`, `DoOnlyStr`. Better use the unquoted syntax here, like `set ExcludeStr=findstr /I /V "\Master Files \Training \Software"` and `set DoOnlyStr=findstr /I "\US_Site4 \US_Site5" 1^> nul`...

Comment: @aschipfl I tried without those quotes and it doesn't make a difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It was the `1>NUL` that was displaying only the 1 output and when that was in a variable it wasn't behaving as it should, so it was displaying 2 (as it seemed to when I removed it also), But is was a combination of the comment from @aschipfl with removing the " " on the set variables and how I structured it below. So my final solution that worked for me was:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM The Root to start searching from
SET "InstallSets=D:\InstallSets"

REM Folders to not search with in
SET ExcludeStr=findstr /I /v ^"\Master Files \Training \Software^"

REM Folders to search in only
SET DoOnlyStr=findstr /I ^"\US_Site4 \US_Site5^"

for /f "delims=*" %%F IN ('dir /s /b /on "!InstallSets!" ^| findstr /E /C:"Config.xml" ^| !ExcludeStr!') do (
    (ECHO "%%F"| %DoOnlyStr% 1>NUL) && (
       ECHO "%%F"...
   )
)
```

Unsure why the `!DoOnlyStr!` didn't work though and it had to be `%DoOnlyStr%` as I have `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start